# aurelia .passes(function('','','',''))

Tags: validation, aurelia

I thought I had nailed this, seems not. I recieve the following error:

> Unhandled promise rejection Error: Unexpected behavior: a
>   validation-rules-collection should always fulfil

```
                        .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) })
                    .if(() => {
                        return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null})
                        .passes( () => { return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime) })
                    .endIf().isNotEmpty()
```

The first time in the returns a bool. However if false doesn't flag this up. After that I receive the error above.

Also I was hoping that I could add a custom error? And that it would appear on all boxes?

Or so I need to do something like

ensure([..,..,..,..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a-lot of investigation I noted the issue was from my formatting class, it wasn't creating the date/time (using moment.js) correctly (after the user has selected from the calendar), meaning it returned 'invalid date' which you cannot compare on :-|

This will work:

```
this.validator = this.validation.on(this)
                    .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) })
                        .if(() => {
                            return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null })
                            .passes( () => { return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime) })
                            .withMessage('< Valid To')
                        .endIf()
```